# How do I change the page numbering style using the fancyhdr package?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

**MWE :**

```
\documentclass[10pt, letter]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1.250in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter

xxxxx
\clearpage

xxxx
\clearpage

xxxx

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look how it is not Page 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in the preamble, after setting up `fancyhdr` and before `\begin{document}`

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}}
```

This will make the page style `plain`, which is used for the first page of a chapter, to also use the footer style form page style `fancy`. See the `fancyhdr` documentation for details.

Comment: Tried it, and this works. But then the issue is the chapter pages start to get the chapter name on the top-right (header via `\leftmark`) which looks very bad. I don't intend to remove `\leftmark` completely, just from each page where a new chapter begins.

Comment: Add `\fancyhead{}`, see edit.